# sending data to php with ajax.send

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Can someone help me with sending this data to a .php page where I could receive it on my PHP page

javascript:

```
postToSql(){
var ajax;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
 {
          // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
 ajax=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{
    // code for IE6, IE5
 ajax=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
  ajax.onreadystatechange=function()
 {
  if (ajax.readyState==4 && ajax.status==200)
 {
   alert(ajax.responseText); //receiving response
 }
 };

 var name = $("#entry_1274804157").val();
//alert(name);
 var company= $("#entry_1828184698").val();
var phone=$("#entry_2039177352").val();
var email=$("#entry_1545475878").val();
 var comments=$("#entry_1846523632").val();
 var params = {
    "name":name,
    "company":company,
    "phone":phone,
  "email":email,
  "comments": comments
 };     
//var jsonText = JSON.stringify(params);
 ajax.open("POST", "view/templates/includes/insertgoogle.php", false);
 ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
 ajax.send("totalJsonStr="+params);
 //alert(totalJsonStr);
 // alert(params);
 return true;
 }
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<form action="https://docs.google.com/asgsasdfasg/formResponse"  method="POST" id="" target="_self" onsubmit="return postToSql();">
```

EDIT:
This is how I am receiving it:

```
 if(isset($_POST['totalJsonStr'])) 
{
   $jsonVal = json_decode($_POST['totalJsonStr']);
$jsonVal2 = json_decode($jsonVal);
var_dump($_POST['totalJsonStr']);
var_dump($jsonVal); 
var_dump($jsonVal2);
$name = $jsonVal2->{'name'};
$company= $jsonVal2->{'name'};
 $phone= $jsonVal2->{'name'};
$email= $jsonVal2->{'name'};
$comments= $jsonVal2->{'name'};
 mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db("test") or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO  `testgoogle` ( Name, Company, Phone, Email, Comments ) 
VALUES ('$name','$company', '$phone', '$email', '$comments')");
        Print "Your information has been successfully added to the database.";
    return;
}
    else 
{ 
   die("No Data Found");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since nothing was working for me, I finally used jquery ajax which worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use $_GET then,

Remove:

```
ajax.open("POST", "view/templates/includes/insertgoogle.php", true);
```

Add:

```
ajax.open("GET", "view/templates/includes/insertgoogle.php", true);
```

Helpful link: http://www.degraeve.com/reference/simple-ajax-example.php

Comment: I dont necessarily want to receive it with a GET, I just want to receive the data on my php page...

Comment: Link given in post, you can get complete AJAX code from there.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you create the "ajax" object?

```
var ajax;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    ajax=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
    ajax=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
```

from here: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_create.asp

Answer (score 0):

Using **POST** Method,

The perfect solution would be, store all values in an array and send the array as a json request using `json.stringify()`.
In php, Use `json_decode()` to decode your json string.

**UPDATE**

Add this to your javascript,

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function postToSql(){
    var ajax;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      ajax=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
     ajax=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    ajax.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (ajax.readyState==4 && ajax.status==200)
        {
           alert(ajax.responseText); //receiving response
        }
      }
        var name = "1234";
        var company= "1234";
        var phone="1234";
        var params = {
            "name":name,
            "company":company,
            "phone":phone,
        };      
        var jsonText = JSON.stringify(params);
        ajax.open("POST", "view/templates/includes/insertgoogle.php", true);
        ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        ajax.send("totalJsonStr="+jsonText);
}
</script>
<form action="https://docs.google.com/asgsasdfasg/formResponse"  method="POST" id="" target="_self" onsubmit="postToSql();return false;">
```

Add this to php

```
<?php
        if(isset($_POST["totalJsonStr"])) 
  {
        $jsonVal = json_decode($_POST["totalJsonStr"]);
        print $jsonVal->{'name'}; 
        print $jsonVal->{'company'};
        print $jsonVal->{'phone'};
  }
        else 
  { 
       die("No Data Found");
  } 
    ?>
```

Comment: where am i sending data to the php ??

Comment: Sorry, i have missed the snippet. Now check the updated answer.

Comment: I found the issue, since async was set to true, the form was getting submitted before the onsubmit function would finish. Now just please tell me how to retrieve this data in php...either json way or ajax way. The ajax way $name=$_POST['name'] isnt working.

Comment: In the answer, the issue i found is with the script i have set the request header before posting data. Now check the updated answer .

Comment: its already correct in mine. May be I should tell you that all this is happening on the onsubmit function call

Comment: add return false at the bottom of your script and check.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39432/discussion-between-stylojack-10-and-raduns)